# R ggplot, plot multiple regions, each with multiple fill colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to visualise the history of valid data

```
mkts = c('GOLD','SILVER')
dt = CJ(date = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = 1), market = mkts)
dt[market == 'GOLD', hasValidData := (date > '2005-01-01') & (date < '2018-01-01')]
dt[market == 'SILVER', hasValidData := (date > '2010-01-01') & (date < '2018-01-01')]
```

So GOLD has valid data from 2005-2017 and SILVER has valid data from 2010-2017.

I want to plot, for each market, a horizontal region (ribbon?) across the whole x-axis, filled with one colour if it has valid data and another colour if it hasn't.

This is what I tried

```
dt[, yorder := match(market, mkts)]
ggplot(dt) + geom_ribbon(aes(x = date, ymin = yorder, ymax = yorder+1, fill = hasValidData), alpha = 0.3)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion? (Ideally, I want the y-tick-label to be set automatically)

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: @AK88 data is in the data table `dt`

Comment: where are you getting `hasValidData :=` from?

Comment: @AK88, I created fake data. The return of `(date > '2005-01-01') & (date < '2018-01-01')`